# What does this Python function definition mean?

Tags: python

What does this Python function definition mean? I don't recognize the syntax. It doesn't look like any function definition I have ever seen, with the colons,  and the -> after the parenthesis.

```
def new_block(self, proof: int, previous_hash: Optional[str]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
```

I saw this function definition here:
https://github.com/dvf/blockchain/blob/master/blockchain.py

Comment: This is syntax from the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module

Comment: See e.g  http://mypy-lang.org/ for the purpose of this.